# Django ModelForm foreign key optgroup select

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm building a simple Q&A website with `Django 1.8`.
 I want to create select optgroup based on foreing key (details below).

**How can I do that?**

**College**

```
class College(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    university = models.ForeignKey(to=University, related_name='college_list')
```

**University**

```
class University(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
```

**Question**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = RedactorField(verbose_name=u'Vsebina')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    college = models.ForeignKey(to=College, default=1, related_name='questions')
```

**QuestionForm**

```
class CreateQuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'college']
```

**Template (displaying the select)**

```
{{ form.college }}
```

**Current result**
[image]

**Needed result**
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080828/how-to-group-the-choices-in-a-django-select-widget)

Comment: [This post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/02/how-to-implement-grouped-model-choice-field.html) lays out a solution nicely.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I have hit upon a solution to this problem of "displaying ModelChoiceField options categorised by a ForeignKey to another model".

Django added the ability to provide nested optgroups in a ChoiceField a few years back. However there is no automatic way to build nested choices like this from a queryset of nested model instanes.

I managed to solve it using OrderedDict to organise the subgroups into groups, then set the choices to the .items() generator. It's important to realise that **you're dealing with dynamic choices here** as the University and College model instances could change over time.

QuestionForm:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class CreateQuestionForm(ModelForm):
    """
    ModelForm which dynamically builds a nested set of choices for University and College
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'college']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Sets up the fields

        university_college_choices_dict = OrderedDict()  # Abused to sort into groups
        for college in self.fields["college"].queryset.order_by("university__title", "college__title"):
            choice_tuple = (college.pk, college.title)
            try:
                university_name = college.university.title
            except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
                university_name = False  # Ends up in the generic ungrouped bin
            try:
                university_college_choices_dict[university_name].append(choice_tuple)
            except KeyError:
                university_college_choices_dict[university_name] = [choice_tuple]

        self.fields["college"].choices = university_college_choices_dict.items()  # MUST call .items() to extract the nested tuples
```